# Problem tweening MC slow movement with Tweener, even with smoothing

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, smoothing, tweener

I think that **Tweener** is not using fractions of pixels on x,y movement, but that exactly what I need. I read about *rounded* parameter (default:false), that would round pixels, to reduce problems with text, but I want to slowly pan an loaded image, so I don't want to use a rounded value. My code:

```
var bmp = Bitmap(loader.content);
bmp.smoothing = true;
Tweener.addTween(loader, {x: 20.0, time:10, transition:"linear"});
```

Image smoothing works fine, but it slides choppy. It looks like moving 1 pixel at seldom frames, not some fraction of px per frame. I'm considering that flash image smoothing has to deal with fraction of pixels. I searched over stackoverflow, and all I could find was about image smoothing, and not about x,y movement smoothing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this even possible? (I'm not sure). I've always thought of a pixel as 1 light.. You can't light up 1/4 of a globe..?

Comment: Try tracing your `loader.x` values in an `enterFrame` to confirm that. I've never experienced such a behavior.

Comment: Used DanielB idea and trace(loader.x) looked like: -108.57266666666666 and -140.648, so I'm assuming that is not Tweener problem, not even the loader, it seems the bitmap loaded problem, like Jordan pointed out.

Comment: @Marty Wallace, you can have 1/2 pixel in this sense: one original image of one black point moving 1/2 pixel, will be two grey points, as if the point was in between those pixels. I think that is a anti-aliasing effect [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-aliasing). So moving an image with subpixels will give a smooth movement.

Answer (score 0):

If loader.content contains a Bitmap instance, that is your problem. Bitmap automatically snap to a full pixel unlike MovieClip and Sprite. You can change this behavior by setting the pixelSnapping property.

Comment: Edited my class as this:

    var bmp = Bitmap(l.content);
    bmp.smoothing = true;
    bmp.pixelSnapping = PixelSnapping.NEVER;

Still some problem. Do I have to use my bmp on stage, or the loader is fine? Maybe this is happening because I using a mask over the loader?

Comment: Yes if your setting the properties of your bmp instance, use that instance, not the loader just for readability. Why the tween is choppy I can't say. You should probably try setting up a stand alone test with this tweener and a bitmap to eliminate the possibility of the tweener causing the problem.

Comment: I will try to create a simple file to emulate the error and reply here.

Answer (score 0):

If it's choppy only on certain, infrequent frames, it could be the garbage collector doing a sweep in the middle of your movement and causing a slight stutter in performance.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by changing x,y movement to a scaleX and scaleY "movement". As I was using a mask over a big photo, it looks like moving when I scale the photo, but it actualy is scaling.

I know this is not a good answer, but it temporarily solved my problem, since I didn't realy now why in this specific case x,y movement was not smooth. Maybe helps someone with same problem.